# bRasilLegis - XML content does not seem to be XML

Tags: xml, r

Estou tentando baixar os votos dos deputados às proposições em votações ocorridas no Plenário da Câmara dos Deputados, em 2015, através do pacote [bRasilLegis](https://github.com/leobarone/bRasilLegis) no R. Porém quando eu coloco o número da proposição no argumento "numero" da função aparece o seguinte erro:

> Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'Não foi possivel obter os votos dos Parlamentares.

O comando dado foi o seguinte:

```
 votesPec <- obterVotacaoProposicao(tipo = "PEC", numero = 185, ano = 2015).
```

Não estou conseguindo identificar o que posso estar colocando errado no código.

**P.S:** quando coloco o exemplo dado no "help" do pacote:

```
votesPec358.2013 <- obterVotacaoProposicao(tipo = "PEC", numero = 358,ano = 2013)
```

Ele funciona normalmente, então estou supondo que é algo no comando que escrevi.

Comment: Sempre coloque a referencia da onde obteve tal pacote, isso ajuda a encontra-los pra poder testar os exemplos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema não está no seu comando. Aparentemente essa consulta é inválida e o próprio servidor da câmara retorna esse resultado.

```
> httr::content(httr::GET('http://www.camara.gov.br/SitCamaraWS/Proposicoes.asmx/ObterVotacaoProposicao?',
+                   query = list(Tipo = "PEC",
+                                Numero = 185,
+                                Ano = 2015)))
[1] "N&#227;o foi possivel obter os votos dos Parlamentares.\r\n"
```

Tem certeza que uma proposição neste ano e com este número realmente aconteceu?

Comment: Sim, fui verificar e o problema era de fato o ano da proposição.